# How do I copy a foundset?

Tags: javascript, appconkit

So I have the following issue: 
I have a Foundset with a bunch of records, and I'd like to (deep) copy them to a new location, including all values but without the IDs. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please share what code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do an deep copy of an foundset you need the follow steps:

1. Create an empty foundset over `retrieveOrCreateFoundset()`
2. iterate over all records of the foundset, that should copied to a new one
3. get the dataProviders  with something like `rec.dataprovider()`
4. get the value of each dataprovider on a record  `rec.value()`
5. be sure that the uuid dataprovider isnt copy to the new Record
6. set the values to a the new record over the dataproviders
7. persist the changes

Full code example would be:

```
var vMobileController = plugins.iBizClientWebService.mobileController();
var vFoundset = vMobileController.currentFoundset();
var vDatabaseManager = vMobileController.dataManager();
var copyFoundSet = vDatabaseManager.retrieveOrCreateFoundset("<datasource>:<label>");
 for (var index = 0; index < vFoundset.size(); index++) {
     var rec = vFoundset.record(index);
     var loc = copyFoundSet.newRecord();
        var newRecord = copyFoundSet.record(loc);            
        var allDataproviders = rec.dataprovider();
        for(var i=0;i<allDataproviders.length;i++)
        {
            var dataProvider = allDataproviders[i];
            var dataValue = rec.value(dataProvider);
            if(dataProvider != "attribute_id")
            {    
                newRecord.setValue(dataProvider, dataValue);

            }
        }
}

 copyFoundSet.saveData();
```